# Application thread remains in WAITING state forever while using logback

Tags: multithreading, logback, appender, rollingfileappender

In my application, I am using logback as a logging framework. The application isn't making progress. To troubleshoot, I took thread dumps (for approx 60 sec), and see the application thread remains in the **WAITING** stage forever, at the point where the **LOG** statement happens.

**The below is the snippet of the AsynAppender:**

```
"AsyncAppender-Worker-ASYNC-FILE" #209937 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0150108800 nid=0x799b waiting on condition [0x00007f01a8b13000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d9216d20> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase$Worker.run(AsyncAppenderBase.java:289)
```

**The below is the snippet of the logback thread:**

```
"logback-6" #807 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f018000b800 nid=0x6b7 waiting on condition [0x00007f0141acd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000640949190> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
```

**The below is the snippet of the application thread:**

```
"application-thread-005-5def0e44-fff5-4184-96dc-ee77349c31de-StreamThread-13" #66 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f01f5e9c000 nid=0x56 waiting on condition [0x00007f01468ea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000006d9216fa0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
```

**The below are snippets of logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

<appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/coldStorage.log</file>
        <append>false</append>

        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>240</maxHistory>

        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %-5level - %msg
                %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    
    
    <appender name="ASYNC-FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>10000</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>20</discardingThreshold>
        <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>


   <logger name="com.example.appl" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC-FILE" />
    </root>
```

The application isn't making any progress because the thread remains in the **WAITING** state forever.

Any inputs what's possible is causing this. I tried to disable FILE altogether, still the same issues.

Comment: Please include the whole thread dump, the logback thread does not seems to be the reason for no progress.

Comment: @samabcde: I reduced the loggers (to a single package only, instead of for multiple loggers) and the threads which were earlier in the WAITING stage moved to RUNNABLE state. I am sure, something related to logback is causing it.